# Определение местоположения Django+Yadex API

Tags: javascript, django, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

На HTML странице выполняется JS скрипт который определяет координаты юзера и отправляет на backend Django 3 AJAX запросом, внутри обычная функция принимает координаты в формате (длина-широта) отправляет API запрос с координатами на API Yandex Geocoder, тот в ответ уже возвращает местоположение юзера.

Все работает отлично, НО только локально.
Если я запускаю на компе runserver и открываю страницу на которой выполняется скрипт определения местоположения, погрешность буквально метров 20, идеальный результат.
А вот стоит запустить с внешним ip runserver (например 0.0.0.0:8000) то определяет только город в лучшем случае...

Даже запускаю 2 сервера рядом, один на 127.0.0.1 а 2-й на 0.0.0.0, открываю 2 вкладки в одном браузере и...
В первом случае правильно определяет даже дом, во втором случае верно только город.

Не понимаю как так получается, если определение координат происходит в JS скрипте НА СТОРОНЕ ЮЗЕРА, сервер в определении координат не учавствует, посмотрел в консоли браузера что там вычисляет JS-скрипт и я действительно получаю разные координаты от html страниц отданных от серверов на разных ip-шниках, как так? О_О

На стороне сервера никаких вычислений не происходит. Сервер только отправляет полученные координаты c html страницы на Yandex Geocoder и
полученный адрес отправляет ответ обратно в html страницу.

Comment: Так откуда у страницы появляются знания о *долготе* и *широте*?

Comment: Я смог исправить)))
Брал координаты из JS API яндекса.
Переделал под navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
Теперь все работает) почти все....

Answer (score 0):

Если геолокация происходит по IP, то такая ситуация возможна. На определение по IP напрямую влияют текущие настройки сети. Если у вас настроены прокси или VPN-соединения, это также может влиять на определение местоположения.